fflush() on invalid FILE pointer returns 0 if compiled with sanitizer
When I read the documentation of fflush, it says that it returns 0, it it was successful and it returns EOF (EOF is on my machine -1) otherwise. (see https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html or https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush)
So I created the following example:
#include<cstdio>
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    FILE* fp = std::fopen("/tmp/test", "w+");
    std::fclose(fp);

    std::cout << std::fflush(fp) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

If I compile it with g++ minimal.cpp or g++ -O2 -DNDEBUG minimal.cpp, it prints -1.
Which is what I expected.
However, when I compile it with g++ minimal.cpp -fsanitize=address or g++ minimal.cpp -fsanitize=thread, it prints only 0.
I can reproduce the same issue with clang too.
How can this be?
I used g++-12 and clang-15 on my Debian 12 amd64 machine. It is always the same result (i.e. fflush returns 0 instead of -1).

std::fflush(fp) after std::fclose(fp) is UB regardless of sanitizers: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fclose.3.html: any further access ... to the stream results in undefined behavior.

According to the documentation (7.19.5.2 in the C99 standard) for fflush:

If stream points to an output stream or an update stream in which the most recent
operation was not input, the fflush function causes any unwritten data for that stream
to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; otherwise, the behavior is
undefined.

That implies if you call it on a file that is not open (as you are doing), you get undefined behavior.
This comes from the C standard historically being a "de facto" standard, collecting together all the common things that different implementations did, rather than trying to "force" different implementors to implement the same thing.  So there are lots of places (particularly with errors or corner cases) where different implementations historically have done different things, so the standard just says "undefined".

A link to a ub description may be useful to OP, so added here.

@JesperJuhl   Is there a similar description of UB for C?   Although both C and C++ have pretty similar notions of undefined behaviour, there are some key differences.   And the undefined behaviour in this case originates in the C standard, not the C++ standard.

@peter They are the same notion. C: "behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data, for which this International Standard imposes no requirements"; C++: "behavior for which this document imposes no requirements".

@molbdnilo  I know the definitions are the same.  But the link given by Jesper also discusses implications of that, with specific examples involving C++ code.   Given how often people here get in an uproar over asking questions about C and C++, and the fact this answer is citing the C standard, having information relevant to C - if that is available (I don't know in this case) - would be appropriate.

@Peter Here is the corresponding page about C.
